# Radio Button OnChange event not firing - BootStrap3

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have these Radio Buttons in BootStrap.

I want to get the value of Radio whenever it is changed.

PLEASE DO NOT link to other questions posted no SO, I have checked all of them but does not work for me

```
<input id="link_type_option1" name="link_type" class="radio" type="radio" value="E" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
<input id="link_type_option2" name="link_type" class="radio" type="radio" value="A" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
```

**Jquery**

```
    $("input[name=link_type]").change(function () {
        console.log("hello");

    });
```

I have also tried

```
"input[name=link_type]:radio"
```

But I can easily get the Checked value on page load by

```
if ($("input[name=link_type]:checked").val() == "A") {
    console.log("Yes it is Article type")
}
```

**EDIT**

If I remove **class="radio"** then OnChange works well but I do not get my Radio buttons as `Forms.Less` renders

Comment: So how do you change the inputs when they aren't visible ?

Comment: Opacity:0 ? How do you access invisible element?

Comment: I am using Twitter BootStrap 3 and I can see elements BTW

Comment: For me it's working after removing styles http://jsfiddle.net/1L4Lhsp1/1/

Comment: @Mani - you're sure you're not using a plugin that creates some fancy fake radio buttons for you ?

Comment: @adeneo But I can get value on page load ....

Comment: Yes ..... ,.......... of no use

Comment: @Mani: Chech this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/L6abynw0). Your code without CSS and with alert.

Comment: Check your console, does browser fire any error ?

Answer (score 2):

I can easily fire OnChange Event of radio button from your code.

What I done : Remove Position and Opacity from Style, So its visible.

And you can get radio button's value by **`this.value`**

Here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/78mpxr5L/2/

**HTML**

```
<input id="link_type_option1" name="link_type" class="radio" type="radio" value="E"> Lable E

<input id="link_type_option2" name="link_type" class="radio" type="radio" value="A"> Lable A
```

**JS**

```
$("input[name=link_type]").change(function () {
    alert(this.value);
    if(this.value == "A")
    {
        alert("Yes it A");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Yes it E");
    }
});
```

Comment: As I said ... I can get the value of chekced radio button on page load but why I cant bind an on change event

Comment: @Mani you can change style From CSS by add !important, check my fiddle example again. I change it. http://jsfiddle.net/78mpxr5L/2/

Comment: @Mani which plugin you are using ?

Comment: I am using this
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/forms.less

Sorry not plugin

Answer (score 0):

After remove style from radio button and try below code which gives me value of radio button

```
<input id="link_type_option1" name="link_type" class="radio" type="radio" value="E" >E
<input id="link_type_option2" name="link_type" class="radio" type="radio" value="A" >A

<script> $("input[name=link_type]").change(function () {
    alert(this.value);

});</script>
```

Comment: @Mani : may be this 'll helpful for you :)

Comment: As I said ... I can get the value of chekced radio button on page load but why I cant bind an on change event.
And I cant change HTMl as it is generated by a plugin

Comment: i m gonna give it try

Comment: This works but I do not get my Radio Buttons rendered in a way my BootStrap `Forms.Less` does .. see my edits question

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myForm">
           <input type="radio" name="weighttype" id="weighttype" onclick="Function()" value="1" checked ><i></i>KG
<input type="radio"  name="weighttype" id="weighttype" value="2" onclick="Function()" ><i></i>Lb's


        </form>

<script>
function Function(){
var wType = document.forms['myForm'].elements['weighttype'];
    var len = wType.length;
    var wTval="";
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++){
        if(wType[i].checked){
            wTval = wType[i].value;
alert(wTval)
        }
    }
    }
</script>
```